# Is HTML5 Required to make Javascript games?

Tags: javascript, android, html

I would like to start learning JavaScript for the purpose of making browser/handheld games and responsive websites. A friend of mine recently showed me HTML5 canvas. I was confused about whether I need to learn HTML5 canvas in order to make games.

I have done some research and all I could find is people talking about HTML5 and JavaScript. So is it necessary?

Comment: no, you don't need canvas

Comment: I've seen games written in old-style html with frames... they doesn't look well but they are still games

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need HTML5 Canvas, however it can be useful in game creation..

It is recommended that you use HTML5! Since it is the current standard.

Javascript will probably be important as well as PHP/MySQL or some other server side scripting language.

Comment: They were, but what is the point of declaring an old archaic doctype?

Comment: Plenty of JavaScript games were developed without HTML5.  It is incorrect to say that it is needed.  You should probably re-phrase your answer to say it is recommended.

Comment: And despite being a standard, HTML5 is not yet fully adopted.  For example, many mobile browsers do not have full HTML5 support.  And unlike desktop browsers, these cannot always be upgraded.

Comment: I think HTML5 should replace the old standards so if you need HTML to develop your game then that HTML standard is HTML5.

Comment: The more it is pushed as the necessary method the more adoption will take place.

Comment: Not so.  Mobile WebViews are part of the mobile OS.  OS updates are pushed out by device manufacturers.  Take Android - only KitKat has a fully HTML5-compliant WebView.  Yet only 30% of devices are on KitKat.  Many device manufacturers simply do not push out updates.  Thus it will likely be several years before the majority of Android users have full HTML5 capabilities.

Comment: i don't think it's possible to not use HTML5 these days; it's not like <video> tags won't play if you use an html4 doctype. nothing has full html5 support, but who cares; it's not an all-or-nothing proposition.

Comment: All I'm saying is that the OP asked the question "is it necessary?".  The correct answer is no.  You can certainly make a case for strongly recommending it, but don't mislead the OP by implying that it is required.